# FackBook Logout for AuthO is not actually logout the user from mobile - Xamarin Forms

Tags: facebook, xamarin.forms, oauth

I'm using `Plugin.FacebookClient` for FB authentication with AuthO SSO at backend using FB SessionToken. I can able to login, retrieve the SessionInfoToken but when try to LogOut using the `FacebookClient.Current.Logout()` method it doesn't logout the user from the app.

When we try to logIn back through FB it directly moving to the Continue page instead of asking username and password.

I tried clear cookies, clearing secureStorage and App preference data but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
_auth0Client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
           {
               Domain = "YOUR_DOMAIN",
               ClientId = "YOUR_CLIENTID"
           });
```

then

```
await _auth0Client.LogoutAsync();
SecureStorage.Remove("accessToken");
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance; 
cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie();
cookieManager.RemoveSessionCookie();
cookieManager.Flush();
```